# How to send protobuf::DynamicMessage with GRPC?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have been playing around lately with `GRPC` and `Protocol Buffers` in order to get familiar with both frameworks in C++.

I wanted to experiment with the reflection functionality, so I have set up a very simple service where the (reflection-enabled) server exposes the following interface file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

service Server {
  rpc Add (AddRequest) returns (AddReply) {}
}

message AddRequest {
  int32 arg1 = 1;
  int32 arg2 = 2;
}

message AddReply {
  int32 sum = 1;
}
```

On the client side I have visibility of the previous method thanks to the `grpc::ProtoReflectionDescriptorDatabase`. Therefore, I am able to create a message by means of a `DynamicMessageFactory`. However, I haven't been able to actually send the message to the server, nor, find any specific details in the documentation. Maybe it's too obvious and I'm completely lost...

Any hints will be deeply appreciated!

```
using namespace google::protobuf;

void demo()
{
    std::shared_ptr<grpc::Channel> channel = grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());

    //  Inspect exposed method

    grpc::ProtoReflectionDescriptorDatabase reflection_database(channel);

    std::vector<std::string> output;

    reflection_database.GetServices(&output);

    DescriptorPool reflection_database_pool(&reflection_database);

    const ServiceDescriptor* service = reflection_database_pool.FindServiceByName(output[0]);

    const MethodDescriptor* method = service->method(0);

    //  Create request message

    const Descriptor* input_descriptor = method->input_type();

    FileDescriptorProto input_proto;

    input_descriptor->file()->CopyTo(&input_proto);

    DescriptorPool pool;

    const FileDescriptor* input_file_descriptor = pool.BuildFile(input_proto);

    const Descriptor* input_message_descriptor = input_file_descriptor->FindMessageTypeByName(input_descriptor->name());

    DynamicMessageFactory factory;

    Message* request = factory.GetPrototype(input_message_descriptor)->New();

    //  Fill request message (sum 1 plus 2)

    const Reflection* reflection = request->GetReflection();

    const FieldDescriptor* field1 = input_descriptor->field(0);

    reflection->SetInt32(request, field1, 1);

    const FieldDescriptor* field2 = input_descriptor->field(1);

    reflection->SetInt32(request, field2, 2);

    //  Create response message

    const Descriptor* output_descriptor = method->output_type();

    FileDescriptorProto output_proto;

    output_descriptor->file()->CopyTo(&output_proto);

    const FileDescriptor* output_file_descriptor = pool.BuildFile(output_proto);

    const Descriptor* output_message_descriptor = output_file_descriptor->FindMessageTypeByName(output_descriptor->name());

    Message* response = factory.GetPrototype(output_message_descriptor)->New();

    //  How to create a call...?

    // ...is grpc::BlockingUnaryCall the way to proceed?
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. Have you found a way to send the dynamic message?

Comment: Maybe this? http://www.grpc.io/grpc/cpp/md_doc_server_reflection_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years, but since you didn't get an answer, I'll make an attempt. You also didn't tag your question with a specific language, but it looks like you are using CPP. I can't provide a solution for CPP, but I can for JVM languages.

First of all, the following is taken from an open-source library I'm developing called [okgrpc](https://github.com/asarkar/okgrpc). It's the first of its kind attempt to create a dynamic gRPC client/CLI in Java.

Here are the general steps to make a call using `DynamicMessage`:

1. Get all the `DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto` for the service you want to call using gRPC reflection.
2. Create indices for all types and methods in that service.
3. Find the `Descriptors.MethodDescriptor` corresponding to the method you want to call.
4. Convert your input to `DynamicMessage`. How to do this will depend on the input, of course. If JSON string, you can use the `JsonFormat` class.
5. Build an `io.grpc.MethodDescriptor` with method name, type (unary etc), request and response marshallers. You'll need to write your own `DynamicMessage` marshaller.
6. Use [ClientCalls](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/ClientCalls.html) API to execute the RPC.

Obviously, the devil is in the details. If using Java, you can use my library, and let it be my problem. If using another language, good luck.